# How should the react component re-render itself when props from redux have been updated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I have a "checkProps()" function that checks if props are empty or not and renders the view if so.

Right now runs on every view render, but since the fn checks just the props, and those come from the redux mapper I think is not a very good approach, performance-wise talking.

I have considered use "componentWillReceiveProps/getDerivedStateFromProps" but according to some sites, that might be an antipattern and I should avoid the use of those methods.

What should be the right way to perform props-ops just when the props are updated and not on every render?

Comment: What about `shouldComponentUpdate` it take 2 arguments `nextProps` and `nextState` you can compare your new values and decide to update or not.

Comment: You can also use `prop-types` to check your props. You can set default values so it won't be undefined or null to remove some bugs. [you can check prop-types documents here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types)

Comment: @octobus afaik "shouldComponentUpdate" runs on every new state/props and I am trying to avoid this just running on new props from the saga.

Comment: @octobus I am using prop-types already :) . My main problem is with redux-saga the first render there is no data (so empty {}/[])  but once data is fetched, there is data, so new props. I just wanna avoid unnecessary checks

Comment: Is your app visibly slow?  Why are you worried about performance?

Comment: @JakeLuby Actually is not. I just want to follow best practices and to know if checking that on "render" is the best approach

Comment: All the tips I've read are to start optimizing if the app feels slow and don't worry about small optimizations until then.  Yeah, you could optimize it so this check only happens if the props change, but then you'll have a different check you're performing on every render instead.  I don't see a ton of value in that and it has no impact on the user experience.  At most I'd leave a TODO with a note that this could be optimized and then move on

Comment: @JakeLuby thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform custom comparison in props (not just shallow) you should use `[componentDidUpdate][1]` which provides you `prevProps` and `prevState` to compare with the current ones:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
    if(prevProps.items.length !== this.props.items.length)
        this.setState({items: this.props.items})
}
```

Comment: Is this the best approach??

Comment: the most common for sure

Comment: Is this more performant than running `checkProps()` on every render?

Comment: The performance is about the same, but you shouldn't track changes in `render`. `componentDidUpdate`, `componentWillUnmount` and `componentDidMount` are the right places to put imperative code